How do I zoom in on a location without an empty?

I'm currently limited in my zoom ability in the viewport. I would like to be able to zoom in on the cursor indefinitely but instead I place an empty there and zoom in on it. The smaller the scale of the empty, the closer the viewport camera comes to the empty. how do I do this better?

Try playing with the Preferences > Navigation > Zoom settings and see what suits you best.

That's a good suggestion, but an empty lets you treat the empty as a center of orbit which is helpful.

Ok. I stumbled upon this by accident. In the side bar menu (n) there is a check box titled Lock to 3D cursor. Now when you scroll to zoom you will continue to zoom until clipping starts.

"Walk" Around
I like to use Walk navigation:

Shift+~ or View ‣ Navigation ‣ Walk Navigation to start.

Left-click mouse (or Enter) to end and keep the current view,
right-click mouse (or Esc) to end and return to previous view.


Use the mouse to look around, change your "forward" direction.
Keyboard to move:

W or ↑ to slide forward, S or ↓ for back
A/D or ←/→ to slide left/right
E/Q to slide up/down (globally)
R/F to slide up/down (locally)
Mousewheel up/down to change how fast the view slides. (If you have a tiny model, you may have to mousewheel down a lot at first to keep from being out of control; change the default value in settings.)


spacebar will slide you forward toward whatever geometry is in the crosshairs, minus some offset.

You can adjust the offset distance in Preferences, under Navigation ‣ Fly & Walk ‣ Gravity ‣ View Height. You have to enable Gravity to be able to edit the "Height", but then you'll likely want to turn it back off (so your camera does not fall through the world when you enable Walk navigation).



For even more key controls, see the documentation. I have found this invaluable to navigating complex geometry, moving in and around it.
...
The "Fly" navigation mode is similar, but instead of W moving you forward for each keypress, or while you hold it, it instead acts as an accelerator pedal. One tap and you start moving. Two taps and you're moving faster. To stop moving, you can't just lift your hands from the keyboard, you must instead slow down to a stop by accelerating backwards with S. I personally don't find it useful during editing.
Zoom to Feature
Alternatively, you can select the geometry you want to inspect, hit Tab to enter edit mode, click to select a vertex/edge/face that you are interested in, press Keypad 0 to zoom the camera to that feature and set it as the point of interest, and then Tab to exit edit mode. Then you can use the mousewheel to zoom in/out, and middle mouse drag to orbit around, this new point of interest.

The zoom most people use is with the mousewheel or ⎈ Ctrl MMB drag, which is kind of similar to using a camera lens, in that it is relative to an origin point, and with min/max amplitude.
But there is also the Dolly, which you can do with ⎈ Ctrl⇧ Shift MMB drag and effectively moves your viewpoint.
